# How do I connect my parachain to Rococo?

Tags: parachain, cumulus, rococo

I have completed the [Cumulus tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/) and tested my parachain on `rococo-local` to work as expected. I would like to connect to the public testnet, but I don't have `sudo` capabilities to add my parachain.

**How do I register my parathread and start producing para-blocks connected to Rococo?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have now streamlined the process: there's a form to fill in "Rococo Slot Request" that asks all the right questions so that we can make that happen quickly for you:

https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 9):

Edit: now the process is to submit [an issue with the Rococo template here](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new/choose), after completion of the [cumulus tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/)

Old: You will need to reach out someone with access to Rococo's SUDO account and this person will help you onboard your parathread to a parachain.

*At the moment of writing this answer that can be done joining [parachain technical element channel](https://matrix.to/#/#parachain-technical:matrix.parity.io)*

If you are interested in knowing what is the purpose of Rococo network, please read this blog post https://polkadot.network/blog/rococo-revamp-becoming-a-community-parachain-testbed/

Comment: The Element channel has been locked now, what should we do to onboard to Rococo?

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new/choose is the new streamlined way

Comment: Thank you. It really helps to streamline the process.